# Where can i get the previous versions of stock apps, like Maps?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, maps

[image]

I am using 1020 on 15230build, there are no roads in maps, only road names, which I found , is common among phones that aren't supported by Microsoft anymore! 
I didn't have this problem while I was on threshold builds, so, am thinking abt downgrading the maps app to the version that came In with 10586 builds! 
So, where can I download previous version of it? Does anyone have it in their drive or is it available in any website! 
Please do help me!